# Magento 2 How can we get product url with product collection?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, phtml, product-urls

I am able to load product collection by using

`[$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')]`

in my phtml file.But in that collection product url is not there how can we get Product url also with that collection.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thagxt/6efbabd952c4b32e1661c167143dafb0

Comment: Collection :http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-product-collection/

Comment: @Jai Please see the below comment given to Rakesh

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-product-url-from-product-object-magento-2/ you can check blog

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**$productCollection = $productObj;**

Gives from product collection url using loop the collection,

```
foreach($productCollection as $_product){ 
   echo $_product->getProductUrl();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Actually I am loading collection in product detail page using this [$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','bundle')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('product_identifier',$productIdentifier);] If I print [$productCollection->getData()] it is not giving products urls.

Comment: Here my need  is I want to give other product links in this current product detail page.

Comment: have you try with, $_product->getProductUrl()?

Comment: yes I tried using [$productCollection->getProductUrl()] but it is not giving any thing.

Comment: plz share your full code

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','bundle')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('product_identifier',$productIdentifier);
        $proColl = $productCollection->load();
        print_r(json_encode($proColl->getData()));die();

Comment: which output is display after call above method

Comment: [{"status":"1","entity_id":"17","attribute_set_id":"10","type_id":"bundle","created_at":"2016-09-24 06:28:54","updated_at":"2016-11-14 07:04:34","sku":"kw_rcp1","product_identifier":"kw_rcp1","is_salable":"1","price":"0.0000","tax_class_id":"0","final_price":"0.0000","minimal_price":"0.2500","min_price":"0.2500","max_price":"54.7500","tier_price":null},{"status":"1","entity_id":"37","attribute_set_id":"10","type_id":"bundle","created_at":"2016-09-24 09:41:12","updated_at":"2016-09-24 09:53:00","sku":"kw_rcp2","product_identifier":"kw_rcp1","is_salable":"1", ....]

Comment: foreach($proColl as $_product){
    echo $_product->getProductUrl();
}

Comment: have you try with foreach loop?

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. +1